# Comparator for sorting by frequency without Creating a Comparator implementation class

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, comparator

Just curious to know on whether we can sort a List according to the frequency of repeated numbers using Java 8 without writing a Custom Comparator class.

I need to sort the given integers based on its frequency and then by the natural numerical order.

I'm getting error at **Comparator.naturalOrder();**

Here is the code which I tried:

```
Integer[] given = new Integer[]{0,0,1,22,11,22,22,11,44,555,55,66,77,88,99};
List<Integer> intList = Arrays.asList(given);


Map<Integer, Long> frequencyMap = intList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
List<Integer> newList = intList.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(frequencyMap::get).thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder())).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(newList.toString());
```

The expected output is

```
[1, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99, 555, 0, 0, 11, 11, 22, 22, 22]
```

PS: Used arrays in first line in order to avoid list.add() in multiple lines and for clear understanding.

Comment: You're printing the original intList here, not the sorted list created by collect().

Comment: Updated the sysout with new list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, Java’s type inference can’t recognize the type of the compared object when chaining `Comparator.comparing(frequencyMap::get)` with `thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder())`. Since the method signature of `Map.get` is `get(Object)`, the compiler infers `Comparator<Object>` as result type of `Comparator.comparing(frequencyMap::get)`.

You can fix this by inserting an explicit type. But note that you are not using the result of `collect(Collectors.toList())` but just printing the original, unaffected `List`. On the other hand, you don’t need the `List` when the array is given:

```
Integer[] given = {0,0,1,22,11,22,22,11,44,555,55,66,77,88,99};

Map<Integer, Long> frequencyMap = Arrays.stream(given)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
Arrays.sort(given,
    Comparator.<Integer>comparingLong(frequencyMap::get)
       .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder()));

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(given));
```

For printing without changing the array you can also use the following alternative

```
Arrays.stream(given)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.<Integer, Long>comparingByValue()
        .thenComparing(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()))
    .flatMap(e -> LongStream.range(0, e.getValue()).mapToObj(l -> e.getKey()))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

This sorts the groups instead of the individual values and prints identical values as often as they’ve been counted.

Answer (score 3):

you need to add a type witness, minor compiler weakness:

```
 intList.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing((Integer x) -> frequencyMap.get(x))
                          .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder()))
        .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Shouldn't `Comparator.comparingInt()` help us here?

Comment: @Lino `comparingLong`, but it is not sufficient, as the problem is that `Map.get`’s parameter type is `Object`, even when the map has the type `Map<Integer, Long>`. But you can keep the method reference when using `Comparator.<Integer>comparingLong(frequencyMap::get) …`